# dplyr: summarize by multiple overlapping group structures and join

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there an elegant way to summarize data by different overlapping (non disjunct) groups and join them?

What I would like to do is:

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(key=1:4, values=1:4)
x %>% group_by(key) 
  %>% summarize(type=1, values=sum(values)) -> tmp1
x %>% mutate(key=key%%2) 
  %>% group_by(key) 
  %>% summarize(type=2, values=sum(values)) -> tmp2
rbind(tmp1, tmp2)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
    key  type values
  <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1     1      1
2     2     1      2
3     3     1      3
4     4     1      4
5     0     2      6
6     1     2      4
```

Is it possible to do this without creating the `tmp1` and `tmp2` objects?

**EDIT: I am looking for a solution that is convenient if there are many (maybe 1e6) overlapping groups.**

For example, another group could be:

```
x %>% mutate(key=key%%3) 
  %>% group_by(key) 
  %>% summarize(type=3, values=sum(values)) -> tmp3
```

Can I summarize over **many** groups and join the results as illustrated above **without** rewriting the code for each grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option if there is any similarity in the function performed would be `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(2:3, ~ x %>%
                group_by(key = key %%.x) %>%
                summarise(type = .x, values = sum(values))) %>% 
  bind_rows(tmp1, .)
```

NOTE: Based on the OP's updated post

Comment: When the `key` and `type` are allowed to have different values, the `bind_rows(tmp1, .)` is not even necessary. That is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you can use `bind_rows({summary 1}, ..., {summary n})`.

```
bind_rows(
  {
    x %>% 
      group_by(key) %>% 
      summarize(type=1, values=sum(values))
    },
  {
    x %>% 
      mutate(key=key%%2) %>% 
      group_by(key) %>% 
      summarize(type=2, values=sum(values))
  }
)
```

This also works, but is not the most elegant in my opinion.

```
x %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarize(type=1, values=sum(values)) %>%
  bind_rows(., {
    mutate(x, key=key%%2) %>% 
      group_by(key) %>% 
      summarize(type=2, values=sum(values))
  })

# A tibble: 6 x 3
    key  type values
  <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
1     1     1      1
2     2     1      2
3     3     1      3
4     4     1      4
5     0     2      6
6     1     2      4
```

Comment: Thanks. - But this is **not solving my problem**. See the edited question above.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @akrun: here is what I ended up using:

```
library(purrr)
map_dfr(c(4, 2),
        ~ x %>%
            group_by(key = key %%.x) %>%
            summarise(type = .x, values = sum(values)))
```

Note that the `key` and `type` variables have different values from what I propose in the question. But they still distinguish the groups correctly.